# How to emulate chrome browser for mobile devices in firefox developers edition

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

Chrome has a nice feature that allows you to emulate devices in the developers console. But I like the style editor packaged with the new firefox (developers edition). How would we emulate a device, like we can in chrome?

[image: emulating a device]

Comment: Do you mean emulate by liking connecting device, and inspecting Cordova/PhoneGap apps from Chrome browser? Can you share screenshot? If this is the fetaure, I love it too and am also trying to get it in Firefox, I only managed to get it so for Firefox on Android and Firefox OS devices but not for Android Corodova Apps.

Comment: You don't have to connect a device,

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot! Ah I see, so you want to just resize the window to different sizes? Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `M` that will open the "Responsive Design View". Also accessible from "Main Menu" > "Developer" > Reponsive Design View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome specific feature is not limited to "*screen size*" (effectively window size) that is possible also with Firefox Inspector as suggested in a comment by **Noitidart** and reported here for completeness:

- You can press `Ctrl + Shift + M` (will open the "Responsive Design View")
- Also accessible from "*Main Menu*" > "*Developer*" > *Reponsive Design View*
- Select "*Responsive Design View*" button in the Toolbox's toolbar

(further references about this in this link [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View))

*Chrome instead, emulates also **User Agent**, for example to trigger specific JS UA checks that enable specific **device detection** features created by web application authors.*

**Currently, Firefox does not have this kind of feature natively** but it was requested several times in official community and it seems in development:

- [Can you please add user agent switcher in tool?](https://ffdevtools.uservoice.com/forums/246087-firefox-developer-tools-ideas/suggestions/5895517-can-you-please-add-user-agent-switcher-in-tool)
- [Give me a way to *fully* emulate the mobile browser in FF desktop](https://ffdevtools.uservoice.com/forums/246087-firefox-developer-tools-ideas/suggestions/5895504-give-me-a-way-to-fully-emulate-the-mobile-browse)

Anyway, you can compensate with some addons like:

- [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/seamonkey/addon/user-agent-switcher/?src=ss)
- [User Agent Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/seamonkey/addon/user-agent-changer/?src=search)

Comment: In Firefox 47 an [option was added to change the user agent string](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=828008) within the Responsive Design Mode.